# Can an android app talk to a native Android service using sockets?

Tags: android, sockets, native

I'm trying to get an android app to talk to a native service (either a cross-compiled ARM binary or a Linux script), and I'm wondering if I can do this using sockets?

Basically, the native service will run upon init, and wait for the app to send it data before doing some other stuff.

Is this possible, and does the android app need root permissions to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.  And no, the app does not need any special permission to do so - for a unix domain socket, you do not even need internet permission.

The only place where you would need special permission would be in what launches the service - essentially, you have to give it oom killer values that will tell android to leave that process alone, and/or set it up to be auto-restarting. Otherwise a resource constrained android system could kill off a mystery process that doesn't seem linked to any particular legitimate activity or service.

A more android-style means of integration would of course be to implement your service more like existing android services, ie, with a stub api that runs in the client process and pushes things through Binder IPC to a service running in a special process (quite possibly the system process).  This might also make it easier to regulate access to your service using the existing package/manifest permission scheme.  But it's ultimately a stylistic thing, and while perhaps to some degree linked to gaining Google acceptance of your device, that is not the only way to make something which works.

Comment: Thanks. I've written a simple Android client app to connects to a 10.0.2.2 socket, but when I try to run it, it hangs. I guess I'm missing the native service. Can I just write it in C and cross compile it as an ARM binary and run it on the device? Does 10.0.2.2 work as the loopback address of the device or is it only for emulators?

Comment: It is only for emulators.  Android does not formally support add-on native services - you can compile and run one, but will need to modify protected settings to keep it running.  You can currentlyuse the ndk build system by changing BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY to BUILD_EXECUTABLE.

Comment: Just to expand on this, while you can't use the special emulator 10.0.2.2 alias on a physical device, you can use 127.0.0.1 which is the standard loopback address.  However, as I mentioned in the answer it may be preferable to use a unix domain socket (local socket in java-speak) rather than an IP socket, as this avoids the need for Internet permission.